# htaccess - rewriting subdomain is breaking relative paths

Tags: .htaccess, path, virtual, relative-path, wildcard-subdomain

My Setup using cPanel:

1. domain.com(/public_html/)
2. mysub.domain.com(/public_html/2013/sitepath/)

Goal: for sub2.mysub.domain.com/save-path-info to redirect to mysub.domain.com/save-path-info without change the url from sub2.mysub.domain.com. In other words, I want anysub.mysub.domain.com to be virtually the exact same as mysub.domain.com.

Code:

```
 Options +FollowSymLinks
 Options +Indexes
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.2013.cqueue\.com$ [NC]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?([^\.]+)\.2013.cqueue\.com$ [NC]
 RewriteRule (.*) /2013/sitepath/$1 [L]
```

The code above was originally in the root directory of mysub.domain.com but it wasn't working until I moved it to the root directory of domain.com. It  successfully keeps the URL and path, however it is breaking the relative path of my templates.

Example: templates normally look for the path to be **/** but, with the rewrite above the templates think they need to look in /2013/sitepath/

***EDIT***

```
 Options +FollowSymLinks
 Options +Indexes
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^\.]+\.mysub\.domain\.com$ [NC]
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mysub.domain.com/$1 [L]

 # -FrontPage-

 IndexIgnore .htaccess */.??* *~ *# */HEADER* */README* */_vti*

 <Limit GET POST>
           order deny,allow
 deny from all
 allow from all
 </Limit>
 <Limit PUT DELETE>
           order deny,allow
      deny from all
 </Limit>
      AuthName domain.com
 AuthUserFile /home/uadmin/public_html/_vti_pvt/service.pwd
 AuthGroupFile /home/uadmin/public_html/_vti_pvt/service.grp
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^\.]+\.mysub\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mysub.domain.com/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply! That does save everything and the template does not break, however, it does not maintain the URL in the address bar.

Comment: If my answer could help you, you can validate my answer. What is the address you set ?

Comment: I plugged in my url. When I tested subone.subdomain.domain.com/index.php it redirected to subdomain.domain.com/index.php. It saved the path (index.php) but it did not keep **subone** in the url. I want to keep subone.subdomain.domain.com in the address bar even though it is actually loading subdomain.domain.com

Comment: That doesn't come from my code because i don't add redirections... What is the code you're using ?

Comment: Entire HTACCESS (mostly applies to the other domain), see post edit.

Comment: It's strange because there are no redirections in your whole code... Are you sure everything in your code is important ?

Comment: The domain that I am using is the main domain on the account (WHM/cPanel) there could be a catch-all from the WHM settings, which I don't have access to at the moment. When I remove the code that you suggested and makeup subdomains (like this.domain.com) the fake subdomain loads with domain.com content.